# Can't scan to exactly letter size (8.5x11) PDF?

Tags: pdf, scanner

I have 3 scanners, none of which can produced a PDF that is exactly 8.5x11. Sometimes, I'll get 8.26x10.76 or 8.24x11.02 - you get the idea.

The native scanning software (on all scanners) allows me to select paper size as 8.5x11/Letter Size but the resulting scans are NEVER exactly 8.5x11.

Is this common amongst all scanners?

FWIW, I have a Brother DCP-7065DN, a Gesteter 620DM and a Scansnap 1300.

It's driving me absolutely bonkers. Help please!

Comment: Scanner software usually has an option to automatically crop the image based on what it detects as the paper edge.  This avoids seeing a dark edge, but it can removed a tiny amount of document.  If exact size is important to you, look for such a setting and disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto on the 'most scanners do it' reply. My scanner has a physical 0.125" gap between the scan area and two paper edges. I have to monkey with paper position if I want the full paper scanned.

As for PDF creation, you can sometimes trim the software DPI settings - doing the math to move from 300dpi to 291dpi or whatever makes the PDF read as 8.5x11.0.